# can not pass all the test cases

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search

problem:
Write a C program to implement Binary Search Algorithm.

Include a function
int BinarySearch (int, int, int *, int x) --- The 1st parameter is the lower limit of the list or array, the 2nd parameter is the upper limit of the list or array, the third parameter is a pointer to the array and the fourth parameter is the search element.

Please note that the index of the search element is returned by the function. If the search element is not present in the array, -1 is returned. 
Assume that the maximum size of the array is 10 . Please note that if a is the array, then a[0] is in position 0, a[1] is in position 1 ...

I tried this ,but it's test cases passes says only 75%,and it can't find the element if n=1;Thanks in advance :)

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int BinarySearch(int, int ,int *, int);
int main(){
  int first=0, last; 
  int a[20],search,s=0,n,i;
  //int j,temp=0;
  printf("Enter the number of elements :\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter the elements :\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
  printf("Enter the element to be searched :\n");
  scanf("%d",&search);
  last=n-1;

  s=BinarySearch(first, last, a, search);
  if(s>0){
  printf("The element %d is in position %d",search,s);
  }
  else{
  printf("The element %d is not present in the array",search);
  }
  return 0;
}

int BinarySearch(int l, int h, int *a, int x)
{
  int mid;
  while(l<=h){
    mid=(l+h)/2;
    if (x==a[mid])
      return mid;
  else if(x<a[mid])
    h=mid-1;
  else if(x>a[mid])
    l=mid+1;
    }
return -1;
}
```

Comment: Debug it. Don't deprive yourself of the pleasure of solving a good puzzle by asking others to do it for you. Find the simplest list (say with just 2 elements) for which your code fails and then step through it line by line. The problem should reveal itself.

Comment: `if(s>0)` is incorrect. The function returns `-1` if the element is not found. If the element in found, it will return its index (starting at `0`). So your test should be `if (s>=0)`

Comment: thanks aziz ,i I overlooked it,(1st element problem solved) but still test cases passing is still showing 75%,  can you say some test cases where it may fail, i am not getting it.thanks again